# Enforce inter-field dependencies during editing?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I'm wondering if anyone knows if you can have something a bit more intelligent than mandatory fields in attribute tables.  Basically I want people to fill in a table & if they type something in Column A they HAVE to put something in Column B, but if they don't put something in Column A they don't need to put something in Column B.

Don't want have to run a check & then chase people down.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define field to field rules using [Production Mapping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//010300000214000000) extension.

[**Validating data during the editing process**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_editing_in_Production_Mapping/0103000000s8000000/)

> Production Mapping provides several ways to validate data while you
> are editing features with Feature Manager. Feature Manager has
> automatic, built-in validation to ensure that attributes meet both
> database and geodatabase integrity rules. You can also build and
> associate additional enhanced validation rules using a Data Reviewer
> batch job.
>
> When editing attributes through Feature Manager, geodatabase and
> database validation occurs immediately. If you change an attribute to
> a value that fails these validation rules, the attribute and value
> turn red on the Create Attributes or Update Attributes window. If you
> try to apply these attribute values, you receive an error.

Alternatively, you could write your own custom editor extension using ArcObjects.